# How can my C/C++ application determine if the root user is executing the command?

Tags: c++, c, linux, root

I am writing an application that requires root user privileges to execute. If executed by a non root user, it exits and terminates with a perror message such as:

```
    pthread_getschedparam: Operation not permitted
```

I would like to make the application more user friendly. As part of its early initialization I would like it to check if it is being executed by root or not. And if not root, it would present a message indicating that it can only be run by root, and then terminate.

Comment: usually we are worried about the contrary: how many programs warn about being root and drop privileges they don't need to run the code more securely?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`getuid` or `geteuid` would be the obvious choices.

`getuid` checks the credentials of the actual user.

The added `e` in `geteuid` stands for `effective`. It checks the effective credentials.

Just for example, if you use `sudo` to run a program as root (superuser), your actual credentials are still your own account, but your effective credentials are those of the root account (or a member of the wheel group, etc.)

For example, consider code like this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() { 
    auto me = getuid();
    auto myprivs = geteuid();


    if (me == myprivs)
        std::cout << "Running as self\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Running as somebody else\n";
}
```

If you run this normally, `getuid()` and `geteuid()` will return the same value, so it'll say "running as self". If you do `sudo ./a.out` instead, `getuid()` will still return your user ID, but `geteuid()` will return the credentials for root or wheel, so it'll say "Running as somebody else".

Comment: Thank you. I have easily created the logic that uses getuid(), and it now does what I wanted.

Answer (score 18):

```
#include <unistd.h> // getuid
#include <stdio.h> // printf

int main()
{
    if (getuid()) printf("%s", "You are not root!\n");
    else printf("%s", "OK, you are root.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for writing `if (getuid())` rather than `if (getuid()!=0)`. :-) If the program is supposed to work with suid though, you may want to use geteuid() rather than getuid().

Comment: @vannitotaro Can your first string be modified to more clearly state that the user is not currently `root`?  It took me a moment to read it as originally intended, since the use of the word "must" is ambiguous.

Comment: @ragerdl after almost 9 years, why not? :D Done.

Comment: -1 for writing `if (getuid())`, the better way would be `if (getuid() == 0)` for root.
Keep it readable.

Answer (score 12):

I would recommend **NOT** making this change, but instead improving your error message. It's doubtful that your application actually needs to "be root"; instead it needs certain privileges which root has, but which operating systems with fine-grained security controls might be able to grant to the application without giving it full root access. Even if that's not possible now, it may be possible 6 months or 2 years from now, and users are going to be irritated if your program is refusing to run based on backwards assumptions about the permission model rather than just checking that it succeeds in performing the privileged operations it needs to.

Comment: With things like AppArmor and SELinux, the reverse is true as well, the process can be running as root and not be able to access some of the things you take for granted (such as being able to write anywhere), so I agree, a more precise error message is the better option.

Comment: I hear what you are saying, but this error message is out of my hands. It comes from perror() and/or strerror(). Moreover, its not immediately clear what the fault reason is.

In this case the errno returned was EPERM which perror() and strerror() translated into "Operation not permitted"

When reading the man pages for pthread_setschedparam() (ACK, I just realized a typo in my error output above), it wasn't immediately
obvious to me which errno was returned, but I eventually honed in on EPERM which has two fault reason which boiled down to "user permissions" or "invalid parameters"

Comment: Although, I suppose I could add this getuid() check if the pthread_setschedparam() fails with EPERM, and if its not root give a suggestion to try again as root?

Ultimately this will protect me from my QA team which will run the application as non-root, it'll fail with the message listed above and they'll log a defect saying its broken. Even if the documentation says it must be run with root privileges. I want to try and make it as clear as possible at the failure point what the problem is.

Comment: When you call pthread_setschedparam, check and see if it fails with EPERM. If so, print a nice message that the user lacks permissions needed for the program to function and suggest running as root.

Answer (score 5):

What you really want to check for is if you have the right capability set (`CAP_SYS_NICE` I think is the capability you need) see man pages `capabilities (7)` and `capget (2)` this way it won't error out if you have the ability to do what you want, but you aren't root.

Comment: Capabilities are very Linux-specific, so using this method will hurt the portability of your program. My favorite way to test for the ability to perform privileged operations is just to try the operation and check for errors.

Comment: @spudd86: Thanks for the tip. I will look into this.

@R..: Thanks for the warning. Coincidentally enough I am writing a Linux application. Granted portability is nice. I could abstract this check so that if it is ported to another platform they can extend the check as appropriate for their platform.

Comment: Well if it's just for the sake of printing friendlier output, you could just put it all inside #ifdef HAVE_CAPABILITIES or such, and thereby skip the code if it's run on other systems.