# Check if Qt c++ application is running as sudo

Tags: c++, linux, qt, raspberry-pi, sudo

I have a Qt GUI application that **must** be ran as sudo.  Right now, I have a script that they are supposed to execute to start program as sudo which adds an argument that I check to make sure they launched from the script.

This technique works, but it doesn't really check if sudo, it only checks that script launched it.

Any thoughts on doing a more precise sudo test?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something can't you just do a conditional check based on the user id and only continue if the user is root?

Comment: It has to be run using `sudo`? Some other mechanism to run it as root isn't adequate?

Comment: Look up the manpage: man getuid

Comment: BTW: You may just install it executable for root only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use getuid or geteuid.

[Here is a previously answered question similar to yours.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214297/how-can-my-c-c-application-determine-if-the-root-user-is-executing-the-command)

Answer (score 0):

Once again, thank you all for help. the

```
if ( geteuid() ) {NotSudoDialog *sw = new NotSudoDialog; sw->show();}
else {MainWindow *kt = new MainWindow; kt->show(); }
```

technique works great.  My "hacky" see if they run from script did work, but this far more elegant.

For those who care, the program has to be ran as sudo because it does low level hardware routines and uses the GPIO on the Raspberry Pi